# Creating dynamic document menu and functions based on JSON object from another source

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

## What I am trying to accomplish:

I want to add specific tags (encapsulated between `{}`) to a document.

This list of tags is populated from a JSON object that is received from my main application.

A top bar menu is filled with tags like {Name} and {Phone} for the user to easily add them to the doc. [See image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b8iyqvegvq3677/Tags%20Menu.JPG?dl=0). This menu is dynamically created with a json object.

I am struggling to find a way that works for all my documents without re-authorization.

## Solution Requirements:

1. Receive json obj when the document is opened (`onOpen`)
2. Create menu based on that json obj
3. Work across multiple documents
4. Automatic (no manual steps)
5. Can't have Google asking for authorization to run the script on newly created docs
6. Accessible to anonymous users

## Attempts so far:

### Copy an existing doc with a bound script

- Positives

  1. I can get the json with doPost
- Negatives

  1. The newly copied docs requires authorization to run the script when selecting a tag
  2. When uploading/converting Word docs to Google docs I would need to transfer the content to a different Google doc that contains a bound script

### Create an Add on

- Positives

  1. Script on all documents
  2. Doesn’t require authorization to run the script for new docs
  3. No need to transfer content from one doc to another
- Negatives

  1. I don’t know how to get the json obj (doPost() is not allowed in Add-Ons)

Another important note is that I am using eval in my script to add functions for each tag. This is needed because the menu is dynamically created and can't send parameters to the function so I have to dynamically create a new function for each tag.

I think an Add-On might work if I can get the json somehow but I'm not sure. Is it possible to send the json as a parameter in the url? I know that's possible with webapps but couldn't figure it out with an add on. Also, does eval work in Add-Ons in the same way as in a regular bound script?

Here is the google script I have so far:

```
var tags = {"Name":"Tags","Items":[{"Type":"Menu","Name":"Contacts","Items":[{"Type":"Tags","Name":"Contact 1","Items":["{$Contact1_FirstName}","{$Contact1_LastName}","{$Contact1_FullName}","{$Contact1_Phone}","{$Contact1_Email}","{$Contact1_Mailing}"]},{"Type":"Tags","Name":"Contact 2","Items":["{$Contact2_FirstName}","{$Contact2_LastName}","{$Contact2_FullName}","{$Contact2_Phone}","{$Contact2_Email}","{$Contact2_Mailing}"]},{"Type":"Tags","Name":"Contact 3","Items":["{$Contact3_FirstName}","{$Contact3_LastName}","{$Contact3_FullName}","{$Contact3_Phone}","{$Contact3_Email}","{$Contact3_Mailing}"]},{"Type":"Tags","Name":"Contact 4","Items":["{$Contact4_FirstName}","{$Contact4_LastName}","{$Contact4_FullName}","{$Contact4_Phone}","{$Contact4_Email}","{$Contact4_Mailing}"]}]}]};
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

// Add Text Functions
var addFunc   = '';
var nAddText  = 0;
var emptymenu = ui.createMenu(tags.Name);
addMenu(ui, emptymenu, tags);
eval(addFunc);


function onOpen() {
  var menu = ui.createMenu(tags.Name);
  nAddText = 0;  
  addMenu(ui, menu, tags);
  menu.addToUi();
}

function addMenu(ui, menu, obj) {
  for(var item in obj.Items) {
    var subMenu = ui.createMenu(obj.Items[item].Name);
    var Type = obj.Items[item].Type;

    if(Type == "Menu") addMenu(ui, subMenu, obj.Items[item]);
    if(Type == "Tags") addTags(ui, subMenu, obj.Items[item]);

    menu.addSubMenu(subMenu);
  }
}

function addTags(ui, menu, obj) {
  for(var item in obj.Items) {
    menu.addItem(obj.Items[item], 'AddText' + nAddText);
    addFunc += 'function AddText' + nAddText + '() { AddText("' + obj.Items[item] + '"); }';
    nAddText++;
  }
}

function AddText(text) {  
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
    var element = cursor.insertText(text)
    if (element) {
      var position = doc.newPosition(element, text.length);
      doc.setCursor(position);
    }
    else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } 
  else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the JSON object used to populate the menu always the same for all files? Have you considered fetching the JSON object with a get request with the UrlFetchApp? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

Comment: The JSON obj will often be different for the different files. I haven't tried UrlFetchApp. I guess I assumed that wouldn't work because Addons don't allow post requests (doPost). I'll check it out. Thanks!